# Iterating analytic self map of the open unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $\phi:\overline{\mathbb{D}}\longrightarrow\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ is  such that $\phi$ is analytic on open unit disc $\mathbb{D}$ and continuous on the closed unit disc $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ with $\phi(0)=0$ and $|\phi'(0)|<1$. Let $\phi_n=\phi\circ\phi\dots\circ\phi\ (n\ times)$ and $K=\cap_{n\geq1}range(\phi_n)$. Suppose $0<\alpha<1$. Then for each $w\in K$ with $|w|=1$, does there exist a sequence $(x_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ in $K$ such that $x_n\rightarrow w$, $|x_n|<1$ for all $n\geq0$, $|x_0|=\alpha$ and $\phi(x_n)=x_{n-1}$ for all $n\geq1$?

Comment: What is a *self-map*?

Comment: I imagine that self-map means that $\varphi : D\to D$. If so, then $K\subset D$, and hence if $w\in K$, then $|w|<1$. So it is impossible to satisfy your assumption, that $|w|=1$!

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis You are right; I think the author meant $K$ to be the closure of the intersection.

Comment: Sorry for the inconsistencies. I made the appropriate corrections.